# Which IDEs / plugins for visual editing of Java Server Faces are available?

Tags: jsf, editor, visual-editor

For the maintenance and migration of some JSF / Woodstock applications (to IceFaces or other frameworks) I would like to know if there are GUI editors for Java Server Faces available. We are currently using Eclipse and NetBeans, but we are open for other development tools. But non-visual editors would be helpful if they offer some support like hiearchy structure view and error checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding Eclipse, I suggest the [JBoss Tools plugin](http://www.jboss.org/tools) for JSF edition.

Comment: @Tarik I generally don't like visual editors, as the code produced by these tools are not really maintainable and efficient (expect maybe the Netbeans Matisse tool to build Swing GUI, which is relatively good IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans and eclipse (as I think).
In plugins you can find everything and netbeans has got self-installer (for plugins).